Finding all automorphisms of the cyclic group of order $10$
I am self-studying abstract algebra, and am trying to solve a problem asking for a description of all of the automorphisms of a cyclic group of order $10$. I'll denote this group by $G$ and call its generator $x$. I think I have a very rough sketch down, but am unsure whether I've filled in all of the gaps. Here is my attempt. (I will leave out the detailed calculations which I did on scrap paper.)

Let $G = \langle x \rangle$ be cyclic of order $10$. Then we can compute the order of each element of $G$ directly:

$e$ has order $1$;
$x^5$ has order $2$;
$x^2$, $x^4$, $x^6$, and $x^8$ have order $5$;
$x$, $x^3$, $x^7$, and $x^9$ have order $10$.

An automorphism $\phi$ of $G$ is uniquely determined by where it $x$: for any $i \in \{1, \ldots, 10\}$, the homomorphism property says that $\phi(x^i) = \phi(x)^i$. As $\phi$ must preserve the order of elements in $G$, it must send $x$ to an element of order $10$, of which there are four. There are therefore at most four automorphisms of $G$:
$$
\varphi_1: x \mapsto x, \qquad \varphi_3: x \mapsto x^3, \qquad \varphi_5: x \mapsto x^5, \qquad \varphi_7: x \mapsto x^7
$$
I claim that each of these are in fact automorphisms of $G$. We will prove this generally. Let $m \in \{0,1,2,3\}$ and define by $\varphi$ the map sending $x \mapsto x^{2m+1}$.
Injective: Suppose $\varphi(x^i) = \varphi(x^j)$ for $i,j \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$. Then the homomorphism property and induction imply that $\varphi(x)^i = \varphi(x)^j$. Without loss of generality, assume that $i \geq j$. Cancelling $\varphi(x)^j$ on the right then gives $\varphi(x)^{i-j} = (x^{2m+1})^{i-j} = e$. This implies by the division algorithm that the order, $10$, of $x^{2m+1}$ divides $i - j$. So $i - j = 10k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. But $G$ is cyclic of order $10$, so
$$
x^{i-j} = x^{10k} = (x^{10})^k = e^k = e,
$$
meaning that $x^i = x^j$.
Surjective: I don't think I can prove this directly when I've made $m$ general, but I can say that the assignment $\varphi$ is injective and $|G| = |G|$, so it has to be surjective and therefore bijective.
Homomorphism: Since $\varphi(x^n) = \varphi(x)^n$ for every integer $n$ (by induction and the fact that homomorphisms carry inverses to inverses), I don't think there is an issue of well-definedness that I need to check. So, if $x^i, x^j \in G$, then
\begin{align*} 
\varphi(x^i x^j) &= \varphi(x^{i+j})\\
& = \varphi(x)^{i+j} \\
& = (x^{2m+1})^{i+j} \\
& = x^{(2m+1)i} x^{(2m+1)j} \\
& = (x^{2m+1})^i (x^{2m+1})^j \\
&= (\varphi(x))^i (\varphi(x))^j \\
&= \varphi(x^i) \varphi(x^j).
\end{align*}
So these are all automorphisms. We also can compute directly:
$$
\varphi_3^2 = \varphi_9, \qquad \varphi_3^3 = \varphi_9 \circ \varphi_3 = \varphi_7, \qquad \varphi_3^4 = \varphi_7 \circ \varphi_3 = \varphi_1.
$$
So $\text{Aut}(G)$ is cyclic of order $4$, generated by $\varphi_3$.

My main concerns about my proof are:
(1) Have I made any oversights in trying to prove the result for a "general $m$"?
(2) Does this method of showing the list of automorphisms is exhaustive works? I ruled out all but $4$ of the $10^{10}$ maps (of sets) from $G$ to $G$, and then tried to show that each of these maps work.
(3) Does the argument for surjectivity work?

Do you know that $Aut(C_n)=U(n)$, the group $(\Bbb Z/n)^{\times}$ of order $\phi(n)$? Since $\phi(10)=4$, this group has order $4$. Since $10=2p$ for a prime $p>2$, the group is cyclic. So your result looks good.

Surjectivity can also be proved by noting that $x = (x^j)^i = (\phi_j(x))^i = \phi_j(x^i)$ (for some integer $i$) (where $x^j$ is a generator ($j = 1,3,5,7$). Since $x$ is in the image, so is every power of $x$ (by the homomorphism property).

Instead of manually checking the generators (as you have done for $m= 10$), you can show (using elementary number theory) that for any cyclic group of order $m \geq 3$, that given a generator $x$ of the group, the remaining generators are precisely the elements $x^j$ (for $1<j<m$, with ${\rm gcd}(j,m) =1$).

$ \varphi_5$ is not an automorphism. The elements of order $10$ are $x,x^3,x^7,x^9$, not $x,x^3,x^5,x^7$. So your "proof" that $x \mapsto x^{2m+1}$ is an automorphism is wrong. If it were right it will apply to $\varphi_5$.

@DietrichBurde The result may be right, but the proof can't be right since $\varphi_5$ is not an automorphism.

@AnuradhaN. $x^5$ is not a generator.

@jjagmath It should be $\phi_9$ and not $\phi_5$ ($x^9$ is a generator). It should be $j = 1,3,7,9$ in my earlier comment. An error on my part without checking.

@jjagmath Thank you for pointing this out. If I instead required that $m = 0,1,3,4$, would this same proof be valid?

If you set $m=0,1,3,4$ but you don't use in your proof that $m \ne 2$, then your proof would apply also to $m=2$ which would be wrong.

@jjagmath I see what you're saying. I think I can pinpoint exactly where I use it. If $x^{2m+1}$ has order $2$, then $m \neq 2$. I rely on the fact that the order of $x^{2m+1}$, which is $10$, divides $i - j$. Does this work?
